# How to open buffer data of PDF from Autodesk Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have a data pdf that loaded from the server with buffer format.I try to convert this data to open it on viewer but impossible. Does any solution for it ? Thank a lot !

Comment: firstly, Forge Viewer does not support PDF buffer data. While it can load local PDF directly without translating. The extension Autodesk.PDF can read the local PDF. The usage is inidaated in the blog https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/fast-pdf-viewingmarkup-inside-forge-viewer. So maybe you could simply download the file to local and load it to Forge Viewer?

Comment: Yes, i have tried to download it to local server ,  save it as PDF file and load it to Forge after. But i try to find the way  download the data directly to front-end not via local server for purpose of free up the storage capacity of the local server.

Comment: where the PDF buffer data comes from? On client side, you could also download buffer data, then you call the corresponding endpoint to start a downloading process. In addition, I do not know how your server is, if you can download to server, and your client side gets the data from server, finally delete the data of server to free the space

Comment: Data come from google drive cloud. I down load it to local server and delete it after. Thank you very much .